# React does not know when i render the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component `Edit` it renders a form in 2 different routes (`Create` and `Edit`).

```
var App = require('./app.jsx')
    Route = App.Router.Route,
    DefaultRoute = App.Router.DefaultRoute,
    Brands = require('./views/brands/index.jsx'),
    BrandsEdit = require('./views/brands/edit.jsx'),
    DefaultLayout = require('./views/layout/default.jsx');

<Route handler={DefaultLayout} name="dashboard" path="/">
    <Route handler={Brands} name="products" path="/products" />
    <Route handler={BrandsEdit} name="products-create" path="/products/create" />
    <Route handler={BrandsEdit} name="products-edit" path="/products/:id/edit" />
</Route>
```

If I am at `EditRoute` the component request data from server to fill the inputs else it just show the form....

This request is done in `componentDidMount` (as the React docs says to do)…

Here's my problem: If I am at `edit` (`/brands/1/edit`) and go to `create` (`/brands/create`), my component does not pass through `componentDidMount`. Why? It's like my component remains for the next page.

Obs: The render method is called. And I am using react-router.

Comment: React-router did not call `componentDidMount` when transition from `/brands/1/edit` to `/brands/create/ `. You could use `componentWillReceiveProps` if you don't wont to change path rules. [ref.](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md#important-note-about-dynamic-segments).

Comment: Check the solution for this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562482/utilizing-componentdidmount-when-switching-between-different-instances-of-the-sa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562482/utilizing-componentdidmount-when-switching-between-different-instances-of-the-sa): I believe it is the same issue.